# get required fields from json schema

Tags: python, json, jsonschema

I'm trying to test a lot of json documents against a schema, and I use an object with all the required field names to keep how many errors each has.

Is there a function in any python libraries that creates a sample object with boolean values for whether a particular field is required. i.e.
From this schema:

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "type": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "position": {
            "type": "array"
        },
        "content": {
            "type": "object"
        }
    },
    "additionalProperties": false,
    "required": [
        "type",
        "content"
    ]
}
```

I need to get something like:

```
{
  "type" : True,
  "position" : False,
  "content" : True
}
```

I need it to support references to definitions as well

Comment: have you looked at [python-jsonschema](https://python-jsonschema.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)? You can extend with your custom checker/validators.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know of a library that will do this, but this simple function uses a dict comprehension to get the desired result.

```
def required_dict(schema):
    return {
        key: key in schema['required']
        for key in schema['properties']
    }

print(required_dict(schema))
```

Example output from your provided schema

```
{'content': True, 'position': False, 'type': True}
```

Edit: [link to repl.it example](http://repl.it/zcT/2)

Comment: This answer won't work with nested schema or an array schema.